# What causes these blocks to not align at the top?

Tags: html, css

I'm still learning my way around CSS. I have a row of li blocks and they're not aligning at the top. I can deduce that somehow the p block somehow pushes the li up, but I don't know why. Can anyone explain?

http://codepen.io/mesu/pen/bVoOrg

```
li {
  display:inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 450px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inline-block` elements by default align to `baseline` (I believe). You can change this with:

```
li {vertical-align: top;}
```

So the `more information` text of the first div is aligning with the `h3` in the second div.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
li {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  height: 200px;
  width: 450px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @Shaymol Bapary: Post your own answer. Don't add it to other people's answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: table; width: 100%;` to the p elements.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BomLMp